# Sorting: Return an array with new positions of each element

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I need to sort an array whilst also returning an array which contains the sorted positions of the original elements. (N.B. not an argsort, the indexes to sort the array)

At present this requires two steps:

1. An argsort
2. A scatter operation on a new array
   i.e. pos[argsort[i]] = i

I feel like I am missing a trick here.   Is this a well known algorithm that I have overlooked that can be achieved in one step?

Step 2 can also be implemented with a search, but I think the scatter is more efficient.

I have included some example python code to illustrate the problem.

```
import numpy as np

l = [0,-8,1,10,13,2]

a = np.argsort(l)
# returns [1 0 2 5 3 4], the order required to sort l

# init new list to zero
pos = [0 for x in range(0,len(l))]

# scatter http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gather-scatter_(vector_addressing)
for i in range(0,len(l)):
        pos[a[i]] = i

print pos
# prints [1, 0, 2, 4, 5, 3], i.e. each original indexes new position in the sorted array
```

Searching for references to this problem has left me frustrated and maybe that I am missing the correct terminology for this type of operation.

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: I have done this several times before without even knowing that that trivial transformation someone decided to call it *Gather-scatter*. Still, I can't see why you are so fixated with this

Comment: Sorted positions of original elements are given by argsort. Your code prints original positions of sorted elements.

Comment: Also notice that you can achieve the same by applying twice the `argsort` function, but obviously this is suboptimal

Comment: @Alexander The reason why I am thinking about this is that I feel like the result (new position of sorted elements) could be calculated in place during the sort.  It seems fairly fundamental so I thought that it might have a well known solution.  


I'm attempting to optimise the performance of an algorithm which contains the steps above which is running on a GPU.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple implementation, although it's not "in-place" in any meaningful sense.  I'm not sure what you mean by "in-place", since the output is an np.array of type int and the input could contain doubles.

Updated in response to @norio's comment and to clarify intent:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np

unsorted = np.array([0,-8,1,10,13,2])

def myargsort(numbers):
  tuples = enumerate(numbers) # returns iterable of index,value
  sortedTuples = sorted(tuples,key = lambda pair: pair[1])
  sortedNumbers = [num for idx,num in sortedTuples]
  sortIndexes   = [idx for idx,num in sortedTuples]
  return (sortedNumbers,sortIndexes)

sortedNums, sortIndices = myargsort(unsorted)

print(unsorted)
print(sortedNums)
print(sortIndices)
```

Comment: It looks this method needs sort operation twice. The original method looks more efficient because it needed sort operation once and list traversal once.

Comment: @norio, not sure exactly what I was thinking 3 years ago, but looking back at the original question, I doubt that my version actually accomplishes what he wants, which maybe is your point.  Although there is only one sort, there is a gather operation to apply the result to the list of numbers.

Comment: I somehow mistook `np.argsort` in `print(..)` in your previous version as a part of the algorithm. That's why I wrote "sort operation twice". I am sorry. I withdraw my comment above. (You are right about the difference between the output of your previous function and what the OP wanted, but I was too careless to notice it.)

Comment: I still think that your `sortedIndices` is the same as `np.argsort(unsorted)`, which is not what OP wanted...